# Change Redirect in Laravel after Registration

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

When I register, I land on "Page not found". However, the user is created and stored in the database. I just want after registering that the user is redirected to the login page. I have already tried to change the $redirectTo parameter and also tried to override the variable with the redirectTo method, all does not work.

I've been trying to find the error for 2 hours, I can't find anything on the internet.

Code:
RegisteredUserController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        .......
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        ......
    ]);

    $user->attachRole('user');

    event(new Registered($user));

    //Auth::login($user);

    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);

}
```

RegisterController

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

RouteServiceProvider

```
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
```

After registration, the user is saved, but then just comes "Page not found". I tried to change the parameters from RouteServiceProvider and RegisterController, but it does not work.

Comment: Which page is not found?

Comment: what route on the "page not found"?

Comment: Post your code what route you have used to redirect without seeing code we can not tell you exactly what that problem would be?

Comment: I have posted the code above